# Menu animation sliding horizontally

Tags: css, animation, menu

I am looking for solutions menu exactly like on this template: http://avonmore.gtcreators.com/index-main.html

I mean this hamburger menu animation and sliding submenu to the left.

Thank you!

Comment: Please see [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and [The perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/).

Comment: This is not a code dump site! What have you tried?